# Inserting new users in database

Tags: php, registration

I´m trying to insert new users in my database, but everytime i do that, my page only refreshes, instead of headind to the location that it should.The query is the correct one.This is the code that i'm using currently.

```
<?php
require_once('bd.inc.php'); 
if (!empty($_POST["submit"])){
if($_POST['submit']==1){}
// verificar se foi submetido o formulário... se sim verificar dados submetidos e enviar info para a base de dados
$nome1 = $_POST['1_nome'];
$nome2 = $_POST['2_nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

    //          Cmd Inserir   Tabela                valores
    $comando = "INSERT INTO utilizadores VALUES ('', '$nome1', '$nome2','$email','$username','$password','2')"; // pergunta a enviar à BD
    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao,$comando) or die ("Operação inválida");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($ligacao))
         echo "Operação efectuada";

    header('location: backoffice.php?msg=ok');// passamos a variavel msg por get de forma a podermos apresentar a informação de sucesso na página de listar utilizadores
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href='css/login.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <title>Backoffice</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" style="max-width:400px;margin-left:450px;margin-top:90px;">
<form name="formulario" action="registar.php" method="post" />
<legend>Registe-se</legend>
<p>Primeiro Nome</p><input type="text" class="form" name="1_nome"/> </br>
<p>Segundo Nome</p><input type="text" name="2_nome"/> </br>
<p>Email</p><input type="email" name="email"/> </br>
<p>Username</p><input type="text" name="username"/> </br>
<p>Password</p><input type="password" name="password"/> </br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" />Registe-se</button>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the user being entered into the database; or is it just the `location` being the problem? Also what is the reason for `if($_POST['submit']==1){}`?

Comment: No, the condition is preventing the from even running the query.

Comment: This will help you: <button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">Registe-se</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few problems are some invalid HTML, the `</br>` should be `<br />`. The `<form>` should be closed before the outer `div`, etc. But the main problem, and the reason why nothing seems to be happening is because of your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" />Registe-se</button>
```

The value of `$_POST["submit"]` is dependent on your `value` attribute, which in your case because there is none it will always be empty. Simply assign a value to your button that isn't `1`

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="someValue" />Registe-se</button>
```

Or rather check for other values such as if `$_POST['1_nome']` is empty if you do no wish to assign a value for your submit button. This will allow your code to get to your query.

Comment: And how do i prevent from the condition runnig if the form is empty?

Comment: @user3375665 You would do a similar thing, but for your form field values. So if you wish them all to be filled in you would do a condition such as: `if(!empty($_POST['1_nome']) && !empty($_POST['2_nome']) && ... )`. Or you can check this on the client side using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only refreshes is that nothing in the body of `if (!empty($_POST["submit"]))` gets executed. Because `$_POST["submit"]` contains nothing.

Updating the form element to following should suffice.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value='something' />Registe-se</button>
```